# Make really personalised wordlist file

Tags: passwords, attacks

i want to make a really customised wordfile with:
4 letters first + 2 numbers example: `divo11` or `yeve11`

And not like this: `p0oiw1` or `u4hf3e`

This wordfile is really important. How can I do it?

Comment: Look for the `crunch` program. Also, you can do the same thing with a very simple script.

Answer (score 1):

In bash you can generate all the combinations of the format [a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9] like this:

> echo {a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{0..9}{0..9}

If you want them one per line then try this:

> printf "%s\n" {a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{0..9}{0..9}